# Can I get C# to automatically fill the user Settings into a DataView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a bunch of user settings in `Properties.Settings.Default` and felt/thought that I could simply populate a `DataView` (or something) thus circumventing the need for a "control per setting" and allow me to just add a Setting variable in the future. Is that possible?

Comment: What platform are you using? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? Console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead look at using a PropertyGrid control to host the user settings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: FYI - That control is specific to WinForms. It will not work in WPF or ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks peops. That's exactly what I was after.